# How to sum up value in Excel only when one value is greater than zero

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column containing numeric data, say in column `A1` to `A10`. Now, I want to create another column, say `B1` to `B10`, and have these values equal `X+A1=B1`, where `X` is any value I choose (actually from a set of constants). Now my challenge is, whenever the value in column `A` is `0`, I don't want any value to be shown in column `B`. I.e. if `A3 = 0`, I want `B3` to be `0`, irrespective of the `X` value I input. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=IF(A1=0,0,A1+$E$13`

Where your `X` value is in cell `E13`

Image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Johnny...u just saved a soul. Worked perfectly. God bless.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer (click on the tick next to the answer).